# Adcontrol added in my application not appearing in the device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bing

I'm trying to test an application with Bing Ads. I've added the latest version of the Microsoft Advertising SDK and i'm trying this in a Windows Phone 8 Silverlight App?

This is the xaml code:

```
   <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="app_id" AdUnitId="adunit_id"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" 
                Margin="0,488,0,200"   Width="480" 
                IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" Keywords="Hotels, Travels, Restaurant"/>
```

But the ad is not getting appeared in the device?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For all we know your control is sitting beneath a canvas with a non-opaque background...

Answer (score 0):

You must Have forgot to add `capabilities`

The following ID_CAP capabilities must be included in the manifest of the advertising-enabled app.

```
ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER
ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO
ID_CAP_NETWORKING
ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER
ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT
```

Comment: I did check now, I've enabled all the capabilities you've mentioned. Could there be a mismatch in the version of the Advertising SDK and the project?

Comment: yes it can be, but you can listen for an ErrorOccurred event. This event will fire whenever an ad fails to download or display.

Comment: So if this gets fired what could be the reason for the ads not getting displayed?

Comment: you can get Reason in e.Error

Comment: Don't forget that you can't display Ads in the emulator (only the test mode works in the emulator)

Comment: @Fabrice yeah I was aware of that. And I did test in my device.

Answer (score 0):

try to check internet connection in your device then set the Visible property ,Enable property

```
   <UI:AdControl ApplicationId="app_id" AdUnitId="adunit_id"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" 
                Margin="0,488,0,200"   Width="480" 
                IsAutoRefreshEnabled="True" Visible="visible" IsEnable="True" Keywords="Hotels, Travels, Restaurant"/>
```